# styling conflict android actionbarsherlock with preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

```
<style name="GCTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"> 
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDown</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
</style> 

<style name="MyDropDown" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"> 
   <item name="android:popupBackground">#7D7D7D</item>
</style> 

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">  
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#7D7D7D</item> 
</style>
```

The following code styles my action bar such that the title of the action bar is white and the action bar is bluish. The problem that I am faced with now is that, since I am using the Theme.Sherlock.Light, the settings on options menu will not display properly.
Setting in the option menu extends `PreferenceActivity` and consists of the following code,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.perferences);
    }
```

The main problem here is that, the textColor for the action bar is set to be white and also the background that appears on this page is white, making the text impossible to read ... Does anyone have an idea so as to solve this problem.

I did try using this code

```
View v = new View(this);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

in the settings activity, but it did not work.

Comment: So as I understand you want to change the ActionBar's title text color to white, but using `<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>` change the other text's color to white too, right?

Comment: @Android-Developer yes ... it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of using `<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>` to set your title's color to white you should use this :

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplications" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.SubTitle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.SubTitle</item>
</style>
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thank you loads ... you are a life saver man ... but what is the logic behind the earlier code that I did write, such that it didnt work and how does the code you just mentioned work ??? I am really new to these stuff so I'd be thankful if you'd explained :)

Comment: setting `android:textColor' in your theme means that the textcolor in whole application will be set to white.

Comment: I have another problem that I would like to ask ... From android 3.0 and higher, the actionbarsherlock dropdown menu's font appears to be black as opposed to being white. I did try various stuff like referencing the Text Appearance of the Spinner as well as the pop up and the drop down, but to no avail. Please do help.

Comment: I have the same issue and I still don't have a solution till now.